# Where can I find the shortcut for automatic formatting of the source code in the development environment of Uniface 10?

Tags: uniface

Unfortunately I can't find a place in the development environment and in the manual of Uniface where there is a shortcut to format the source code automatically.

Thus the question arises, is there a shortcut in Uniface for an automatic formatting of the source code?